# Strange Nautilus view in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: nautilus, 16.10

Why different windows of Nautilus when running as root (launched with sudo) and as usual user? Primarily the question about title bars.

Root user:

[image: Nautilus window with root user]

Usual user:

[image]

PS: Used Arc theme. But there is same behavior with other themes.

Answer (score 1):

Elevated privileges.Grants the ability to eject system volumes

Also the profile settings in /root

Comment: Thanks, I understand this. Main question about window title bar.